# Android : take Data in ListView

Tags: android, mysql, xml, database

Actually in my project, I'm blocked. So, for the first time I ask the community of Stackoverflow. I'm new in development.

So, I have a MySql with my datas and I wan't to see in my application the items of users.

For that, I've this :

```
public class SuccessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private ListView listView;

    protected String meubles[] = new String[100];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_success);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

        this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);


        new SuccessActivity.Recup().execute(id);

    }



    //PRIVATE CLASSE POUR AFFICHER LES MEUBLES
    private class Recup extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                //url d'ou reside mon fichier php
                url = new URL("http://opix-dev.fr/mytinyhomme/personne/afficher.meuble.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                // parametrage du  HttpURLConnection pour recevoir et envoyer des donner à mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Append parameters to URL
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("id", params[0]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();


                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resulta) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            if (resulta.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {


            } else if (resulta.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || resulta.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {


            } else {
                try {


                    JSONArray nom = new JSONArray(resulta);
                    System.out.println(nom);

                    String meubles[] = new String[100];

                    for (int i = 0; i < nom.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonobject = nom.getJSONObject(i);

                        meubles[i]= jsonobject.getString("nom");
                        System.out.println(jsonobject);

                        System.out.println(meubles);
                        item.setText( meubles[i]);



                    }
                        System.out.println(meubles);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

The `file.php` is correct because the `JSONArray in System.print` is ok But I've try with some TextView for display the board at the end, but I did not succeed.

How I can use the `meuble[0] , meuble[1], meuble[2](it's board of String name of items) in a ListView ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to show your data in a listview,

**Modified onPostExecute() method:**

```java
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resulta) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            if (resulta.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {


            } else if (resulta.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || resulta.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {


            } else {
                try {


                    JSONArray nom = new JSONArray(resulta);
                    System.out.println(nom);

                    String meubles[] = new String[100];

                    for (int i = 0; i < nom.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonobject = nom.getJSONObject(i);

                        meubles[i]= jsonobject.getString("nom");
                        System.out.println(jsonobject);

                        System.out.println(meubles);

                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,meubles);

                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



                        System.out.println(meubles);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
```

**What's added?**

You need an adapter to show items in a listview. You can create your custom adapter class by extending an arrayadapter or you can use an arrayadapter without customizing it as shown.

**Added code:**

Create a new adapter,

> ArrayAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

Set adapter for your listview,

> listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: Ok thanks for the syntax And it's work now ! Thanks dev'